# How do I input multiple data into database for one item but display only data that is searched for?

Tags: php, mysql, database

For example:

If someone is searching for the grocery store that sells the cheapest onions in the city they live, the directory will show them the grocery stores that sell onions with the pricings.

The person has to type out the word "onion" (without quotes) into the search box, then the commend will search the database for all grocery stores with "onion" their product list.

Here's the problem: if you are inserting data for a single grocery store with lots of products, how would you insert all those products but allow the site to search for one?

If one column in the database for one product contains 50 items....so all 50 items are in one cell, how would the database search that one cell for the specific query "onion"?  Or would I have to configure it so that each item out of all 50 items gets their own cell?  So it would be 50 rows in 1 column for every product?  But that would be tedious since each product would have their own database table.

I guess the question is:

[image]

Would a database be able to search one single cell for a specific item if there are multiple items?

Comment: are you familiar with the `LIKE` operator? You can do something like `store.products LIKE '%Onion%'`

Comment: Or create separate table for product/store_id releationships

Comment: @nlloyd - but what happens if I want the search box to give auto-suggestions?  eg: if they search "onion", the word "onion" will pop up as a search suggestion.

Comment: @user2984757 f0r this purpose you have to learn about ajax for auto suggestion. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Comment: there's no shortage of ways to do this. You could parse unique strings from each `store.products` or create a new table of user search terms that can be user specific. Just a note in database design, the typical way to store data is ["normalized"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization); i.e. no duplication. Following this good design principal would probably lead you to something like @charliefl suggested

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In your case, you can use LIKE in order to match a set of characters in your table cell, with the entered name.

For example: `select Store from tablename where products like '%onion%';`

The % means any number of characters before and after onion.

Though, I recommend that you follow the principle of *one entity per table.*

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the replies that you have may apparently work, they will be far too slow once you have any reasonable amount of data in the table. Your schema does not even make it to First Normal Form which among other things states that a field must only contain "atomic" values. You really need to learn the basis of databases (for example, database tables to not have "cells").

It is too much to try to explain here all about database design and normalisation, but suffice to say that you are effectively asking the wrong question, because you are starting from the wrong place.